# Explanation for what the main characters found in the Eye of the World's magical tunnels

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, eye-of-the-world

I just finished reading the first book of Robert Jordan's scifi *Wheel of time* series: the *Eye of the World*, and my question contains a subtle spoiler (so be careful!).

In the Eye of the World, the main characters travel to

> the Ways

and inside of them, they find

> Trollocs that have been turned to stone. And although the Black Wind is described as being capable of draining your soul or causing you to go mad, nowhere does Jordan state that the Black Wind can turn living creatures to stone.

So I ask:

> What turned the Trollocs to stone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to [chapter 45](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/The_Eye_of_the_World/Chapter_45), it's implied that the Trolloc tampering with the path has led to errors where they were transported into solid rock, not that they were turned into stone.

> Loial points out that they are close to a way that will take them to Tar Valon but stops when it becomes obvious that someone has tampered with the path. Chiseled marks wound the stone. Lan is galvanized. Moiraine says, "this explains much," and continues on by admitting fear and then saying that the marks were made by Trollocs or Fades; the markings are Trolloc runes. The Trollocs have figured out how to use the Ways, in fact that is how they must have gotten to the Two Rivers--through the Waygate at Manetheren. She makes other mental connections with regard to the appearance of Trollocs around Caemlyn noting that there is a Waygate in the Blight. She also concludes that they (the Trollocs) don't know all the ways yet else an army would have poured through the gate they used at Caemlyn.
>
> Lan, who has moved a small distance away shouts back, "They don't use the Ways easily." Moiraine leads the group to him where his lantern reveals horror. Rand sees Trollocs frozen in the rock and are locked forever in fear, and where the rock has bubbled, more fearful Trollocs are revealed deeper in the rock. The bridge ends a few feet beyond the frozen Trollocs, the signpost laying in a thousand shards. All are heavily affected by the sight.

Answer (score 5):

The actual passage is as follows (TEOTW, Ch 45):

> "[Trollocs] don't use the Ways easily," Lan called. His lantern was no more than twenty spans off, but the light of it was only a dim, fuzzy ball that seemed very distant to those around the Guiding. Moiraine led the way to him. Rand wished his stomach were empty when he saw what the Warder had found.
>
> At the foot of one of the bridges the frozen shapes of Trollocs
> reared, caught flailing about them with hooked axes and scythe-like
> swords. Gray and pitted like the stone, the huge bodies were half
> sunken in the swollen, bubbled surface. Some of the bubbles had burst,
> revealing more snouted faces, forever snarling with fear. Rand heard
> someone retching behind him, and swallowed hard to keep from joining
> whoever it was. Even for Trollocs it had been a horrible way to die.

When Nynaeve asked Moiraine about it, she speculated that it was the result of Shadowspawn traps laid by the male Aes Sedai who made the Ways:

> Nynaeve rounded on the Aes Sedai. “How can you take it so calmly? The
> same could happen to us!”
>
> “Perhaps,” Moiraine said serenely, and
> Nynaeve ground her teeth so hard Rand could hear them grate. “It is
> more likely, though,” Moiraine went on, unruffled, “that the men, the
> Aes  Sedai, who made the Ways protected them, building in traps for
> creatures of the Dark One. It is something they must have feared then,
> before the Halfmen and Trollocs had been driven into the Blight. In
> any case, we cannot tarry here, and whatever way we choose, back or
> ahead, is as likely to have a trap as any other. Loial, do you know
> the next bridge?”

Although Trollocs use the Ways several times during the series, they are not shown to encounter any other such "traps", so another possibility (which may not have occurred to Moiraine at this point in the series) is they were caught in a bubble of evil.